# Compare each row of one file with each row of another file

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files:

file1

```
cat file1
A,1
B,2
C,2
D,3
```

file2

```
cat file2
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
D
```

Desired output

```
cat output
A,A,1 
A,A,1
A,A,1
B,B,2
B,B,2
C,C,2
C,C,2
D,D,3
```

As you can see, each line of `file1` should be matched with each line of `file2` and if they match, the line from `file1` should be added to the matched line in `file2`. I have tried `join` but it doesn't work. I guess the search needs to be recursive but I am not sure how to do it when two files are involved.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{print $1, a[$1]}' file1 file2
A,A,1
A,A,1
A,A,1
B,B,2
B,B,2
C,C,2
C,C,2
D,D,3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
join -t',' -o'1.1,2.1,2.2' file2 file1
```

this line does it.